# Need help displaying some posts with a shortcode in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, shortcode

I'm trying to print out custom posts through a short code in wordpress.  Everything seems to be working except I can't get the content of the post to print out.  My code is below.

```
function sc_liste($atts, $content = null) {
   global $post;
   $myposts = get_posts('post_type=section_modules&category_name=aboutiia&order=ASC&posts_per_page=3');
   $retour = '<div class="container-fluid sectionBoxContainer"><div class="row-fluid">';
    foreach($myposts as $post) :
            setup_postdata($post);
         $retour.='<div class="sectionBox span4"><h2>'.the_title("","",false).'</h2><div class="hrule_black"></div></div>'.the_content();
    endforeach;
    return $retour;
    wp_reset_query(); 

}
add_shortcode("list", "sc_liste");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `the_content()` is going after you close the `div.sectionBox`, and you never close the original opening `div.container-fluid` and `div.row-fluid`.

This would produce:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">

        <!-- start loop -->

        <div class="sectionBox">
            <h2>title</h2>
            <div class="hrule_black"></div>
        </div>
        Post content would get dumped here

        ... next post ....

        <div class="sectionBox">
            <h2>title</h2>
            <div class="hrule_black"></div>
        </div>
        Post content would get dumped here
```

And that's it.

You should close the first 2 divs.  And, you might want to put the content inside the `.sectionBox`.  Maybe that's part of the problem...

**Also**

Code placed after a `return` statement won't run (ex: your `wp_reset_query()`).

Answer (score 0):

Oops didn't realize I didn't close the divs was in a rush a guess.  I fixed some of the tags and formatting not it is printing but rather then printing in the sectionBox div it is printing before the container-fluid div.  Here is my new code

```
function sc_liste($atts, $content = null) {
   global $post;
   $myposts = get_posts('post_type=section_modules&category_name=aboutiia&order=ASC&posts_per_page=3');
   $retour = '<div class="container-fluid sectionBoxContainer"><div class="row-fluid">';
    foreach($myposts as $post) :
            setup_postdata($post);
         $retour.='<div class="sectionBox span4"><h2>'.the_title("","",false).'</h2><div class="hrule_black"></div><p>'.the_content().'</p></div>';
    endforeach;
    $retour .= '</div></div>';

    return $retour;


}
add_shortcode("list", "sc_liste");
```

Comment: You should not be using `the_title` and `the_content`, as they **`echo`** the values, and a shortcode shouldn't echo anything. You're looking for `get_the_*`.

Comment: Better saying, remove `setup_postdata` and use simply **`$post->post_title`** and **`$post->post_content`**.